# App works on Simulator but not device. Weird error message? XCODE

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

As the title says, the code is perfectly fine and works on the simulator as expected. When I try to run the same code on device, I get this error: `2014-10-09 23:00:07.180 Color Speed[1129:538481] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[_NSPlaceholderData initWithContentsOfFile:options:error:]: nil file argument'` What does this error even mean? I would try to debug, but I have no idea where to start and have verified every line of code works (I barely started this project).

Comment: If I had to guess from the error, it looks like you're trying to access a file that doesn't exist on the device `-[_NSPlaceholderData initWithContentsOfFile:options:error:]: nil file argument` The issue could be that you're accessing something from a place where the simulator can get to it (possibly inside the iOS Simulator's files, which are in Application Support,) but the device cannot. Check your code for any hard-coded paths that might lead to a place on your computer rather than accessing the device's filesystem.

Comment: I'd refer you to my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/26256119/3981769
Try it with the exception-breakpoint and tell us where and with what parameters your code fails

Comment: I have no file paths in my code whatsoever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look the reason. It show that your file argument is nil. Most of such cases are due to different file path between simulator and device. Check your code about loading file and compare the path between simulator and device.

Comment: I don't want any unanswered questions on SO. Now that I have enough experience, I'm pretty sure that this was the issue.