# xcode crashing once I build app even though it has no errors

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

My question is I am having an issue building my first iPhone app and even though xcode is saying that the build succeeded and there are no errors. As soon as the app opens up in the simulator it crashes and gives me the following error:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCellContentView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c4ae60'`

I don't really know what to do so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: See http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: BTW - this is known as a "runtime" error since your app is crashing when it is run. Just because your code compiles doesn't mean it is going to work.

Comment: You are passing an illegal argument to a procedure at `runtime`. Your code compiles fine, but it can't predict everything you are going to do at runtime.  IN order for us to help with your exact problem you need to post a [Minimum, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code, so that others may examine and determine the problem.

Comment: `selector` is another word (for all intensive purpose) method or function and this error is telling you that the Class `UITableViewCellContentView` has no method of the signature `setText:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [my answer under this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26256119/3981769) can help you.

Try to use an Exception-Breakpoint to identify where and under what circumstances your exception is thrown.